# A question involving $\limsup$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $(a_t)_{t \in \mathbb{R^+}}$ be a sequence of real numbers. Consider the subsequence $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}^*}$ of the sequence $(a_t)_{t \in \mathbb{R^+}}$. I'm trying to figure out if it's true that
$$\limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \log a_n = \limsup_{t \to \infty} \frac{1}{t} \log a_t.$$
Since any natural number is also a real number, any subsequential limit of $\frac{1}{n} \log a_n$ is also a subsequential limit of $\frac{1}{t} \log a_t$. Hence we shoul have
$$\limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \log a_n \le \limsup_{t \to \infty} \frac{1}{t} \log a_t,$$
from the definition of $\limsup$. So, my question is: do we have here equality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counter-example: Take $a_n=1$ for $ n \in \mathbb N$ and $a_t=e^{t^{2}}$ for all other $t$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider :
$$a_t = \left\{ \begin{array}{cl}
1 &\text{if } t - \frac 12 \in \mathbb Z\\
0 & \text{else}
\end{array}
\right.$$

Then, $\limsup a_t = 1$ and $\limsup a_n = 0$.